# How to remove all coupon validation in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to remove all coupon validation in woocommerce plugin core code? I want to remove the `validate_product_categories()` function in core code for Class WC_Coupon.in WooCommerce **class-wc-coupon.php** file without editing plugin?
Is there any hook for to do that in functions.php?